# How to rewrite raw sql query with join to EF Core LINQ?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM public.lifecycle_data lifecycle_data 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM public.users 
     WHERE id = 123) AS t1 ON lifecycle_data.reference = t1.id
WHERE updated IS NULL
ORDER BY created DESC
```

I want to rewrite this query with EF Core LINQ and I tried this:

```
var users = db.LifeCycle
                .Where(l => l.Updated == null)
                .Join(db.Users,
                    l => l.Reference,
                    u => u.Id,
                    (lifeCycle, user) => new User()
                    {
                        Id = lifeCycle.Id,
                        FieldOne = user.FieldOne,
                        FieldTwo = user.FieldTwo,
                        Created = lifeCycle.Created
                    })
                .Where(u => u.Id == 123)
                .OrderBy(c => c.Created)
                .ToList();
```

But it's interpreted as:

```
SELECT 
    l.id AS "Id", u.field_one AS "FieldOne", u.field_two AS "FieldTwo", l.created AS "Created"
FROM 
    lifecycle.lifecycle_data AS l
INNER JOIN 
    users.users AS u ON l.reference = u.id
WHERE 
    FALSE
ORDER BY l.created
```

Comment: You don't. It's the ORM's job to generate the query, especially the JOINs from the relations between *entities*. There are no tables in EF (or any other ORM), there are entities. What you ask could be just`dbContext.Users.Include(u=>u.LifeCycleData).Where(u=>u.Id==123);`

Comment: Which EF version are you using? EF Core 5 introduced [Filtered Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include) which allows writing `dbContext.Users.Include(u=>u.LifeCycleData.Where(l=>l.Updated==null).OrderBy(l=>l.Created)).Where(u=>u.d==123);`

Comment: `INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM public.users WHERE id = 123)` is a pointless optimization, the server would do that anyway. `.Where(l => l.Updated == null)` is it actually possible for `Updated` to be null, that wasn't in the SQL?

Answer (score 1):

It's the ORM's job to generate the query, especially the JOINs, from the relations between entities. There are no tables in EF (or any other ORM), there are entities. A DbContext isn't a model of the database and LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL.

The equivalent in EF Core 5 and later would be a [Filtered Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include), assuming `User` has a `LifecycleData` collection property:

```
var users = dbContext.Users
                     .Include(u=>u.LifeCycleData
                                  .Where(l=>l.Updated==null)
                                  .OrderBy(l=>l.Created))
                     .Where(u=>u.d==123);
```

Comment: but what if the user doesn't have that property? They do not have a direct relationship, the lifecycle table links to many tables